# C# - Is it possible to parse a Type from a string - e.g (Pseudo code) Type t = Type.Parse("Int32");

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to parse a Type from a string in C# - e.g (Pseudo code)

```
Type t = Type.Parse("Int32");
```

This is for an application that dynamically maps data from varying formats to our inhouse format, and I need to be able to dynamically determine type to do this.

(.NET 3.5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you want `Type.GetType` (the static method, not the instance one inherited from `object`).

For example:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```

Note that for types outside the current assembly or mscorlib, you'll need to specify the type's [fully qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), which will be the full name (with namespace) *and* the display name of the assembly containing that type, separated by a comma—for example:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection,System");
```

Comment: Watch out, that only works for types from the current assembly or mscorlib.dll.  The OP is almost certainly going to have to supply the fully qualified type name.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for pointing that out; I added an example for that case (which, you're right, seems likely).

Comment: @Dan Tao: Bless you, my child. Your StringCollection example was especially helpful when working with a custom SettingsProvider and overriding GetPropertyValues() when you have a StringCollection setting. Using Type.GetType(SettingsPropertyValue.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName, ...) fixed the null that was previously being returned when not using the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the full-qualified name, but you can use [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```